# cin inside while loop is being ignored, need

Tags: cin

I am having an issue with a `cin` command on a project I am working on.

In the code below, where the command is asking the user to enter 1 to try again or 2 to quit, I have the command `cin  >> keepGoing;`

For some reason, this is completely being skipped. I have tried both clearing the buffer and using `cin.clear();` with no such luck. Here's the code:

```
int searchDisplay()
{
    bool flag = false;
    vector<Client> store;
    Client foo;
    int i = 0;
    int totalIt = 0;
    Client search;
    char response;
    int keepGoing;
    string input;

    fstream customer("customer.dat", ios::in);

    if (!customer)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file. Program aborting." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    i = 0;

    while (!customer.eof())
    {
        store.push_back(foo);

        customer.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&store[i]),
                    sizeof (store[i]));

        i = i + 1;
    }
    totalIt = i;

    while (flag == false)
    {
        i = 0;
        cout << store[i].name << endl; //test to see what is in store at i = 0

        cout << "Name:                                " << endl;
        cin  >> search.name;

        while (i < totalIt - 1)
        {
            if (search.name == store[i].name)
            {
                flag = true;
                cout << "Name:             " << store[i].name << endl
                     << "Address 1:        " << store[i].address1 << endl
                     << "Address 2:        " << store[i].address2 << endl
                     << "Phone:            " << store[i].phone << endl
                     << "Account Balance:  " << store[i].acctBal << endl
                     << "Last Payment:     " << store[i].lastPay << endl;
                cout << endl << "Strike any key to continue";
                cin.get(response);
            }
            else
            {
                i = i +1;
                cout << "searched " << i << "times" << endl;
            }
        }
            
        if (flag == false)
        {
            cout << "There is no record of that name in our files. Hit 1                  
                                      to try again or any number to quit:" << endl;

            cin.clear();
            cin  >> keepGoing;    //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
            
            if (keepGoing != 1)
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = false;
            }
        }

    }

    customer.close();
    return 1;

}
```

All other questions posted I have found with similar problems had answers that either didn't work or caused an error I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me :(

(Sorry, I should really comment but I'm new and my rep is horrible.)

I tried your code with a dummy `Client` class and some `#includes` (and a customer.dat file and commented out the `cout << store[i].name << endl; //test to see what is in store at i = 0`) ...

And it worked. <strike>100%</strike>

Ok it crashes if I don't enter `1`. But if the point is it's reading the `cin >> keepGoing;` just fine.

It looks like your code is fine. Hope this was in some way helpful.

P.S.: My includes were thus:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add:
Compiled on Windows 7 x64 NetBeans MinGW.

Comment: i apprciate that it works for you. that helps me realize that it isn't a coding issue. i will try to move from a different compiler and see if that helps any.